# curve fitting of a non-linear model in shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to fit some non-linear models in shiny to identify the best parameter values and then use them as initial values. As an example, I'm using a non-linear logistic model.

Below is the computational routine:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("beta_0", "Beta 0:", min = -100, max = 100, value = 1),
  sliderInput("beta_1", "Beta 1:", min = -1000, max = 100, value = 1),
  sliderInput("beta_2", "Beta 2:", min = -100, max = 100, value = 1),
  
  plotOutput("grafico")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  logistic_model <- function(x, beta_0, beta_1, beta_2) {
    return (beta_0 / (1 + beta_1 * exp(-beta_2 * x)))
  }
  
  data_modelling <- structure(list(x = c("10.66", "16.87", "12.57", "15.92", "9.71", 
                                         "15.92", "17.35", "6.37", "11.94", "11.14", "8.91", "13.05", 
                                         "17.67", "10.66", "17.19", "7", "10.82", "11.62", "16.71", "18.3", 
                                         "11.78", "12.25", "8.91", "10.98", "17.03", "15.92", "12.73", 
                                         "12.41", "11.78", "18.62"), y = c("15.2", "18.3", "15.7", "17.5", 
                                                                           "14.8", "16.7", "19.8", "10.3", "18.6", "14.4", "14.3", "17.8", 
                                                                           "21", "18.8", "18.9", "13.7", "17.6", "17.5", "19.6", "18.8", 
                                                                           "15.3", "16.8", "15.1", "14.7", "18.5", "17.9", "17.8", "16.9", 
                                                                           "17.5", "18.7")), row.names = 31:60, class = "data.frame")
  data_modelling$x = as.numeric(data_modelling$x)
  data_modelling$y = as.numeric(data_modelling$y)
  
  output$grafico <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_modelling, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_point() +
      stat_function(fun = logistic_model, args = list(
        beta_0 = input$beta_0,
        beta_1 = input$beta_1,
        beta_2 = input$beta_2
      )) +
      labs(x = "X", y = "Y")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem I'm having is that the curve doesn't appear on top of the actual sigmoid-shaped data. I've tried numerous parameters and my model is correct (the model considered was based on this article: 10.34188/bjaerv4n1-035), see:

[image]

Comment: I attempted your code outside of shiny, and it doesn't work there. I suggest you simplify your problem significantly to work on just static inputs _first_. Once that's working, try to make it dynamic. (For that reason, please remove the [tag:shiny] tag and all shiny components of the question in order to get the proper results. FYI, I see no glaring errors in your shiny code.)

Comment: The code is working, there are no problems in it. However, notice that although I give countless values ​​to the parameters, I never have the curve in a sigmoid shape.

Comment: That's my point: there's no "curve" in your curve, even outside of shiny. Said differently, are you certain that you can get exactly the curve you want outside of shiny, and then take those exact parameters and it behaves differently inside a shiny app? I'm not convinced, and troubleshooting static code on the console is typically easier than debugging a shiny app (though not a lot here).

Comment: I reproduced your environment but outside of shiny by grabbing your data, then `input <- list(beta_0=17, beta_1=-1000, beta_2=42)` (as a placeholder to emulate being inside a shiny reactive environment), and then ran your `ggplot(..)` code, and got exactly the same plot as you show there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adjusting the beta 2 slider to have 0.1 step, you can get the curve.

[image: output]